# Delete request on node.js REST API works fine from postman not from app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, mongoose

I have a rest API and an app that uses it. The app and postman can both make get requests perfectly. The problem is that on delete requests the app does not work **Most of the time** but postman works every time. The app also always receives an OK if it works or not. Any help would be appreciated. I am using Node.js and MongoDB for the api and Xamarin for the app

Delete code on server:

```
// Delete a fish with the specified fishId in the request
exports.delete = (req, res) => {
  console.log("Atempting to delete fish with id: " + req.params.fishId)

  Fish.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.fishId)
    .then(fish => {
      if (!fish) {
        return res.status(404).send({
          message: "Fish not found with id " + req.params.fishId
        });
      }
      if (!Fish.findByID(req.params.fishId)) {
        return res.status(200).send({
          message: "Fish deleted sucsessfully"
        });
      }
      return res.status(500).send({
        message: "Could not delete fish with id " + req.params.fishId
      });
    }).catch(err => {
      if (err.kind === 'ObjectId' || err.name === 'NotFound') {
        return res.status(404).send({
          message: "Fish not found with id " + req.params.fishId
        });
      }
      return res.status(500).send({
        message: "Could not delete fish with id " + req.params.fishId
      });
    });
};
```

Comment: well what error message do you get?

Comment: is the first console.log printed all the time?

Comment: From the [MCVE] document: _Describe the problem. **"It doesn't work" is not a problem statement.** Tell us what the expected behavior should be. Tell us what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Put a brief summary of the problem in the title of your question._

Comment: I don't get an error message, it gives the OK response whether it works or not. the first console log is printed.

Answer (score 0):

Just wondering why is this with no callback/.then?

```
if (!Fish.findByID(req.params.fishId)) {
  return res.status(200).send({
    message: "Fish deleted sucsessfully"
  });
}
```

Isn't [findByID](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById) async just like [findOneAndRemove](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndRemove)?

Comment: It had the same behavior I added this check so I don't think it is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

findByID is async yes, you should handle it that way, or maybe a solution could be to check with [ObjectID.isValid()](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html#ObjectID.isValid) before? Then check for the resolved document would be just enough.